# Python - Extracting per line regex matches of variable amount

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to single out certain regex matches and printing them as strings in a different file.

I have input lines like this:

```
Example one A;B;C;D;E
Example two FF;EE;WW;DFG;E;J
Example three C;UFT;B;VB
```

And I want output like this:

```
Example one 1:A 2:B 3:C 4:D 5:E
Example two 1:FF 2:EE 3:WW 4:DFG 5:E 6:J
etc
```

The elements I'm looking for are capitalized letters only, seperated with a semicolumn, no spaces, line ends with `\n`, elements range from at least one to multiple ones and they can consist of a single letter or multiple

I've gotten as far as creating output like this

```
def read_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r", encoding="utf-8") as pro_file:
        for line in pro_file:
                matches = re.findall('([A-Z]+[;,\n])', line, re.DOTALL)
                counter = len(matches)
                for element in matches:
                    new_matches = re.findall('[A-Z]+', element, re.DOTALL)
                    print(new_matches)
```

This gives me all the cap. letter elements in the entire file individually as a single-item list. I feel like I'm off the track here... How do I work with what I got so far to achieve the desired output? Or is there a cleaner, simpler way? I'm thinking maybe I could somehow slice output by the number the `counter`variable provides?

Output so far:

```
['A']
['B']
['C']
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine what your existing code does, taking the first line of the input as an example.

```
for line in pro_file:
```

`line` is `'Example one A;B;C;D;E\n'`

```
    matches = re.findall('([A-Z]+[;,\n])', line, re.DOTALL)
```

Now `matches` is `['A;', 'B;', 'C;', 'D;', 'E\n']`

```
    counter = len(matches)
```

`counter` gets set to 5

```
    for element in matches:
```

Taking the first element as an example, this sets `element` to `'A;'`

```
        new_matches = re.findall('[A-Z]+', element, re.DOTALL)
```

Now `new_matches` is an iterator over all the runs of capital letters in `'A;'`. There is one such run. Do you understand why `new_matches` will *always* be a list of exactly one element?

What you probably should do, instead of iterating over `matches` and processing each element individually, is apply a transformation on each element of `matches`, which you can do with a generator expression. Continuing with the above example, we had `matches` as `['A;', 'B;', 'C;', 'D;', 'E\n']`. For each `element`, you can extract the part that is only capital letters with

```
re.match('[A-Z]+', element).group()
```

You can get an iterator of (number, match) tuples with `enumerate()`.

```
enumerate(re.match('[A-Z]+', element.group() for element in matches))
```

Take a close look at what this does to make sure you understand. It goes over each `element` in `matches`, for each one extracts the leading capital letters, and pairs each with a number. (It's a generator so if you try to print it, you'll need to convert it into a list or something first, otherwise you'll get not-particularly-useful output.)

Then, for each tuple, you can convert it into a string using

```
('{}:{}'.format(number + 1, letters) for number, letters in enumerate(...))
```

and finally, join all these with spaces using `' '.join()`. Putting it all together,

```
' '.join(
    '{}:{}'.format(number + 1, letters) for number, letters in
    enumerate(re.match('[A-Z]+', element.group() for element in matches))
)
```

Then you will have to reattach the first part of the line.

## A better approach

That was more or less the minimal way to fix your existing code. But in practice, I'd just use `split()` (or `rsplit()` which works from the right): first you break the line on spaces, and then take the last component and break that on semicolons.

```
words = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
words[0] + ' ' + ' '.join(
    '{}:{}'.format(n + 1, l) for n, l in enumerate(words[-1].split(';'))
)
```

Comment: thank you for your cohesive reply, that cleared up things for me, it's working now!